# New to Android Dev. Cant figure out whats going on here

Tags: android, android-studio, android-2.2-froyo, wear-os

[image]

This is the code that gets automatically generated when creating a new wearable project. so why doesn't it compile?

Comment: Did you do 'Clean your project' ? Go to 'Build' --> 'Clean Project' after making the default project ? Try to do that and see if these errors are gone

Comment: I tried what you suggested still fails. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

`WatchActivity` does not exist. Android Studio 0.8.0 had wrong templates and would create this code, but the proper class to extend is just the plain old `Activity` (this bug is already fixed, as of 0.8.1 and 0.8.2 new activites no longer extend WatchActivity).

See [Compiling simple wearable app in Android Studio - WatchActivity not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657160/compiling-simple-wearable-app-in-android-studio-watchactivity-not-found)