# Compiling simple wearable app in Android Studio - WatchActivity not found

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I followed the instructions at [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) to create a simple mobile/wearable app in Android Studio. However, it won't recognize any of the classes specific to the wearable SDK, giving the error "cannot resolve symbol **______**". The screenshot at [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cSIu.png) is what I am seeing.

The following is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
         applicationId 'com.example.lsykora.androidwearwidget'
         minSdkVersion 'L'
         targetSdkVersion 'L'
         versionCode 1
         versionName '1.0'
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use      this dependency.
// You must install or update the Support Repository through the SDK manager to use this dependency.
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

I have installed all SDK's using SDK manager and I have tried tinkering with the minimum, target, and compile SDK's in the build.gradle file, setting them to 19, 20, or Android-L, but I'm having the same results - program won't compile because of these unrecognized classes. Any input is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't extend `WatchActivity` (that class doesn't actually exist).

The base class for Android Wear activities is just the standard [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

(Also, if you're using Android Studio 0.8.0, update to 0.8.1 -- 0.8.0 has a bug in its templates and creates new Activities using `extend WatchActivity`, which is actually invalid).

Comment: Thank you, this solution fixed the problem I was having. Unfortunately I have a new issue, detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662804/failure-install-failed-older-sdk-when-installing-android-wear-sample-app), if you want to check that out.