# Cannot resolve symbol AndroidWear compilation Issue Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, wear-os

Hi im trying to set up and environment for Android wear and run a simple hello world
I have installed all necessary stuff (or i think so..) but im getting this compilation issue
"Cannot resolve symbol AndroidWear" when my main activity extends the android wear class    `MyActivity  extends WatchActivity`

What i have installed

- Android Studio
- SDK build tools and api 19, 20 and L preview

im definitely missing something... but i dont know what ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling simple wearable app in Android Studio - WatchActivity not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657160/compiling-simple-wearable-app-in-android-studio-watchactivity-not-found)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24658310/82788

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `WatchActivity`. Use the standard `Activity` instead.

The `WatchActivity` doesn't exist in current SDK.